# SQLCipher with Android. Creation works fine, select + insert don't

Tags: java, android, sqlite, sqlcipher

Good afternoon.

I am creating an encrypted database file in an Android Application with the following code:

```
String dbPath = context.getDatabasePath(NAME_OF_MY_FILE).getPath();
SQLiteDatabase sampleDB = SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase(dbPath, "password", null);
```

This works fine and the file is created although when trying to access this encrypted file I get multiple errors such as:

no such table TABLE_NAME and 
file is encrypted or is not a database

I am simply using the same code to open the file for editing, since the function is called `openOrCreateDatabase()`. I assume the process to open the file is simply the reverse of creating, and you pass the original password?

Please note I am using the correct import:

```
import net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteDatabase;
```

and initializing `SQLiteDatabase.loadLibs(this);` in the `onCreate()` method.

Can someone please point out where I'm going wrong if they have any idea.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

After your call to `SQLiteDatabase.openOrCreateDatabase`, are you creating your database schema there, or are you creating a sublcass of the `net.sqlcipher.datdatabase.SQLiteOpenHelper` to manage database migrations?  Without that your table name would not exist.  Maybe you could show more of the code to help diagnose the problem you are seeing.

Comment: Upon creating the file, I immediately create multiple tables using sampleDB.execSQL. As you just said, when I try to open the file in another view I assume all tables are intact (as they are when unencrypted) and attempt to insert.

I do not use SQLiteOpenHelper.. do I need to?

Comment: Depending on your needs, usage of the `net.sqlcipher.database.SQLiteOpenHelper` will be quite beneficial as it will allow you to perform schema migrations as your application changes.  It sounds like you are reimplementing this.  Possibly check out the [docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteOpenHelper.html).  Also, to rule out your application logic, try throwing in an insert statement following your table creating and see what occurs.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to paas "password" in that call.